# Unable to loop over table rows to animate respective progress bars

Tags: javascript, for-loop, progress-bar

Ok, for brevity's sake, I'm just including the javascript code itself. If the HTML or CSS is really needed, I'll update the post.

The objective: I've got a table with rows (displaying tasks), and I have a progress bar to the right of each task showing how much time has elapsed.

The problem: only the first progress bar works. All subsequent progress bars just show a completely filled-up bar. Upon looking at the console log, the program isn't looping at all. It performs no calculations for any rows other than the first. I've tried moving various variables inside and outside the loop, but no cigar.

Please forgive me if the code looks terrible and/or the answer is obvious. This is essentially my first real javascript 'program.'

```
var Table = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
var Row = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var rowDisplay = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

function fillBar(timeElapsedPercent) {

    for (i = 0; i < rowDisplay.length; i++) {

        var eachRow = rowDisplay.item(i);
        const interval = setInterval(() => {

            // Grabbing the needed info from the cells
            var taskName = rowDisplay[0].innerText;
            var rawDeadline = rowDisplay[1].innerText;
            var rawStartTime = rowDisplay[2].innerText;

            var bar = document.querySelector('.bar');

            //calculations for the progress bar
            var now = new Date();
            var startTime = new Date(rawStartTime.replace(/(am|pm)/, ''));
            var deadline = new Date(rawDeadline.replace(/(am|pm)/, ''));
            var timeTotal = Math.abs(deadline - startTime);
            var timeTotalPercent = Math.abs(timeTotal / 60000);
            console.log('value for total time in minutes of', taskName, 'is', timeTotalPercent);
            var nowTillDeadline = Math.abs(deadline - now);
            var nowTillDeadlinePercent = Math.abs(nowTillDeadline / 60000);
            var timeElapsed = Math.abs(timeTotalPercent - nowTillDeadlinePercent);
            var timeElapsedPercent = Math.abs((timeElapsed / timeTotalPercent) * 100);

            // moving the progress bar
            bar.style.width = timeElapsedPercent + '%';

            if (timeElapsedPercent >= 99) {
                bar.style.width = '100%';
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, (1*1000))
    }
}

fillBar();
```

Comment: Shoudn't you be looping over `Row` and not `rowDisplay`?

Comment: I just tried Row.length and Row.item(i), but no change in the result.

Comment: You could use the [debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) statement anywhere in your code to see if a certain point is reached. Place a couple of these in your code to see where it breaks. Also use [console.log](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) to see what kind of values are assigned to your variables.

Comment: I've spent some quality time with the debugger and console log. I can't get any useful information out of it. All the definitions appear right. It reaches every line of code, and I know this because the first progress bar works like a charm. The problem is it won't iterate, and I don't know why. One interesting thing I noticed is the `eachRow` variable seems to have no effect. I changed the code to `var eachRow = ""` and the program ran exactly as it did before, running perfectly the first time through and then exiting without iterating. Not sure what that means, but it seems significant.

Answer (score 0):

All right then, time to answer my own question again.

I'll include the HTML for the row, then the Javascript to manipulate it:

```
<td class="col-sm-4">
    <div id="progressBarBackground">
        <div class="bar" id="progressBar"></div>
    </div>
</td>


function fillBar() {

    const interval = setInterval(() => {

        var i;

        for (i = 1; i < Table.rows.length; i++) {

            // grabbing relevant info from DOM
            var taskName = Table.rows[i].cells[0].innerText;
            var rawDeadline = Table.rows[i].cells[1].innerText;
            var rawStartTime = Table.rows[i].cells[2].innerText;
            var bar = Table.rows[i].cells[6].getElementsByClassName("bar").item(0);

            // calculations for progress bar
            var now = new Date();
            var startTime = new Date(rawStartTime.replace(/(am|pm)/, ''));
            var deadline = new Date(rawDeadline.replace(/(am|pm)/, ''));
            var timeTotal = Math.abs(deadline - startTime);
            var timeTotalPercent = Math.abs(timeTotal / 60000);
            var nowTillDeadline = Math.abs(deadline - now);
            var nowTillDeadlinePercent = Math.abs(nowTillDeadline / 60000);
            var timeElapsed = Math.abs(timeTotalPercent - nowTillDeadlinePercent);
            var timeElapsedPercent = Math.abs((timeElapsed / timeTotalPercent) * 100);

            // manipulating the necessary DOM element    
            bar.style.width = timeElapsedPercent + '%';

            if (timeElapsedPercent >= 99) {
                bar.style.width = '100%';
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }
    }, (1*1000))
}
```

So my problems were as follows:

1) The for-loop needs to be inside the interval, not the other way around. I read somewhere that an interval is basically just a timed for-loop. That was a light bulb moment for me.

2) Using `.querySelector()` to get the progress bar only gets the first one, even if it's in the for-loop; to get the progress bar for each row, the `.getElementsByClassName()` method was needed *in addition to* the `.item()` method with its index position, which you would never know from the error code you get if you leave it out. Since I only had one element within the cell to get, its index position is 0.

3) At the start of my for-loop, I changed from `displayRows.length` to `Table.rows.length`, but in order to do that, I had to change the way I defined `var Table`. Instead of `.getElementsByTagName()`, I used get `.getElementById()` -- for my fellow noobs, note it's just one Element, not Elements.

I think those were the three main issues. There were probably other minor issues, but I tried about 100 different things between now and when I first posted the problem, so it's hard to know.

I also made use of console.log at various points while I was troubleshooting everything. I deleted those lines here for the sake of code neatness, but they were immensely helpful.